# VS 2008 MFC - Remove MFC handler

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, command, handler

How do you remove a MFC command handler like ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI from a C++ file?
I can't seem to find a way to do it thru Dev Studio.  If you know how, please explain.

I am using VS 2008.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a handler, you used the drop-down list in the Messages list of the properties pane. When you didn't have a handler, the list had an entry something like `<add> OnXxxUpdate`. If you already have a handler, dropping down the same list will show a `<delete> OnXxxUpdate` -- click that. That just removes the entry in the message map -- you have to delete the function body manually.

Comment: Just to clarify: You can do this from the Class View. AFAIK there is now way to remove a handler from the Resource View.

Comment: Thanks both to Jerry and Dani for your answers. I see what you mean. I hope you have a great day!!!